# QGIS and topological complexities/erros in polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, topology

I am using QGIS 2.14.19-Essen on Windows 10. I have a polygon shapefile of ecorregions in the Southern Cone of South America (Fig. 1), which is composed of 317 different features. I need to make it look like one whole polygon without internal limits. Then, I dissolved it using SAGA's Polygon Dissolve tool, which succeeded to some extet. As can be seen in Fig. 2, two lines remain. Line 1, which corresponds to the northern limit of Argentina, and line 2 which represents the borders between Argentina/Uruguay and Rio Grande do Sul in Brasil.

Line 1 can be easily eliminated using the node tool and selecting all the vertices to be deleted until none remains. Lines surrounding Rio Grande do Sul (No. 2) are a different story (Figures 3 and blown up detail in Figure 4) because the intersecting, zigzagging lines delimiting Southern Brasil (as a separate part) seem to preclude a successful dissolution.

Is there a straightforward way to get rid of those lines and nodes and have one single polygon? I've tried several alternatives using a wide range of pyhton/grass plugins, all to no avail.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]
[image: Figure 4]

Answer (score 1):

#### Make a new polygon that covers the area between the two polygons. Make sure it overlaps both polygons, but doesn't extend beyond their outer edges.

My two polygons:
[image]

Third polygon added:
[image]

#### Select all three polygons and merge them using the "merge selected features" tool in the advanced digitizing toolbar.

[image]

After merging:
[image]